# intent filter for long press, so that i can capture the broadcast and show my app option there like it happens in the share button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

If someone long presses on any text usually the default comes, but I want my app to have an option like "save it in this app"; is it possible to use some intent filter so that I can receive the broadcast of long press?

For example let's say I am reading an email and if I long press on any word normal clipboard options comes first. I actually want to see an option that says "add a word in this app".
How can I make this possible, do i have to receive and interpret the broadcast or what?

I have tried looking everywhere on the internet, but I could not find any solution yet.